# Easy backup of TFS 2012 Express Edition possible?

Tags: tfs, database-backups

I use the TFS 2012 Express edition for personal use (I use mostly it to versionize my sources).

I had a brief look in the documentation concerning backup strategies and it seem to be a hell of work :(. Are there any shortcuts available when I am just interested that my versionized sources can be backuped and restored?

Comment: have you considered using Team Foundation *Service* instead? Then at least Microsoft will be conducting some backups too - comparison: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2013/01/17/team-foundation-server-vs-team-foundation-service.aspx

Comment: If anyone comes here looking for how to do this in TFS **2013** Express (like I did), the Administration Console now has built-in functionality for "Sceduled Backups"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backups made easy with the [TFS Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) "Team Foundation Backup" feature.

It essentially creates a seamless process for backup/restore of the TFS databases.

[image: TFS backup plan]

Comment: is there any way to back up the TFS database without stopping the service?

Comment: @Windy You can backup the database manually via SSMS without stopping the service (but for restoring you must).

Comment: I should describe the question more clearly. For easy data restore, we detach the collection before doing the backup. The detach operation will stop the service (for the collection) temporarily. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @Windy it's not necessary to detach the collection. you can stop the IIS and backup the database to a BAK file without detaching it.

Comment: TFS Power Tools 2012 is now out and it is really awesome how easy it is to create an automatic backup plan :)

Comment: This item is not yet published.

Answer (score 1):

Information provided in answer is based on TFS Standard Edition and not TFS 2012 Express. I have looked all over the internet and found just scripts that does it manually. I have installed the Power Tools Update 1 (**Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 1 Power Tools.msi**) and nothing has changed in the Console whatsoever.

Here is the alternative manual way :: [Backing up TFS 2012 Express](http://tsells.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/backing-up-tfs-2012-express/)

[image]

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Use this link: [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775) for installing the Power Tools including the Backup Assistent

For any reason, the Power-Tools from the Visual Studio Gallery, does not include the Backup Tools. See more in [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19817084/466935).

Answer (score 0):

If it's just backing up TFS occasionally, then I'd just download and install [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593).

In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) ...

1. Connect to "**.\SQLEXPRESS**"
2. Open the "Databases" node in the tree view on the left
3. Right click on each database having a "TFS" part in its name and select the context menu item "**Tasks > Back Up...**"

To restore TFS later (e.g. on a fresh Windows installation), again in SSMS ...

1. Connect to "**.\SQLEXPRESS**"
2. Open the "Databases" node in the tree view on the left
3. Right click on each database having a "TFS" part in its name and select the context menu item "**Tasks > Restore > Database...**"

Comment: While that's fine in a personal context when you can stop your TFS for a backup, you should not do this otherwise, as the backups might be out of sync: *"(...), you should avoid using such individual backups when possible. You might experience unexpected results if you restore from individual backups (...)."* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh561429(v=vs.110).aspx