# Database Backup Tools missing from TFS Power Tools?

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I ran into a situation where i needed the powershell scripts for tfs to be installed on the tfs server (we have everything for tfs on one server). Trying to modifying the install didn't give me the option to install the powershell scripts so i decided to download the newest version of the tfs 2012 power tools and do a uninstall and install. The problem is when i do an install the only components its letting me install is "Best Practices Analyzer" & the "Test Attachment Cleaner". Its not letting me install the "Backup Database Tools" (which is the urgent pressing need right now) or the powershell scripts i was originally wanting to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Aghilas's answer. If you pickup whats in the Visual Studio Gallary:
[Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)

it will not have the backup tools. But if you download here
[Microsoft Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775)

It will have the backup tools. Whats even more MORE confusing is that if you have the tools (in the 2nd link installed) and you try to install the client tools (in the first link) it will ask you if you want to modify the install. Its been awhile since i've installed the tools but i "thought" they used to put the backup tools in and just wouldn't install them if you weren't on the server. I could be wrong though on that. I will try to install "Team Explorer" and see if that allows me to install the powershell scripts (in the Prerequisites for the first link)

Update 2: That was the key. I had to install Team Explorer and then it let me install the powershell scripts. Also it appears that the tools in the 2nd link has everything and the 1st link has everything minus the backup tools.

Answer (score 0):

`Backup Database Tools` is available on `SQL Server Product` not in your `Power Tools`, he contains tools about customizing, for example Test Attachment Cleaner is used for cleau attachment or free storage space

Answer (score 0):

I believe the version of TFS is very important here. Most of these tools are designed for TFS RTM version 12. I had version 11.0 and it just didn't work with the interface.

The easiest item to do is to run it directly C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools\TFSBackup.exe. Once I ran this program it worked however I clearly would like to create a schedule which I suspect can be done using powershell.  The other issue I had was trying to back it up on to the network which I couldn't do as SQL instance was running under a local machines admin account.

Answer (score 0):

The db backup tools were part of TFS 2012 power tools, but it seems they were removed after update 1. Even from the [MS Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775), the latest download lacks the db tools. They are in the Update 1 version, which can be selected above it:

[image]

So if you need TFS db backup tools in the 2012 world, you need the right tools version:

- TFS 2012 (which also means SQL 2012, since TFS 2012 won't recognize SQL 2014)
- [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 1 Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775), with the emphasis on Update 1 rather than any later version than Update 1.

**NOTE** db backup/restore is included as standard in TFS 2013. These tools are for TFS 2012. After installing TFS 2013, I wanted to use the db backup tools, but I found they were not present in the 2013 power tools. The reason is that the functionality is now part of TFS as standard, and is available from the TFS Administrative Console without installing the power tools.